# commited usage discount only for big customers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

currently my company has some small operations on GCloud < 200 $ however we have a really stable workload, which means that a commited usage discount would make our invoice even better.

However after talking with a sales person in my region he said that we aren't "big" enough for a commited usage discount.
Is there a reason for that?

Or would it be better to try to raise the "commited usage" directly from the gcloud interface and hope for a better outcome?

Our Organization ID is 915001879966.

Comment: I believe there's confusion. As answered by FridayPush, you can purchase any CUDs without talking to a sales rep. You can talk to your sales rep if you're beyond 100k spending per year to get some additional discount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can purchase committed discounts for even a single 1 vCPU instance for 1 year. Details on [their documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts). Make sure you read what doesn't apply (dataflow, flex), etc. Also it's region specific, and you can't get instances smaller than 1 vCPU.